# Hold content efficiently

Tags: c#, xna

So I have got this class called `TypingKeyboard`. It's a class that draws a string on the screen as if it is typed by someone, with sounds. I use this for many things, for example in the main menu, credits and the game itself.

```
class TypingKeyboard
{
    SoundEffect foo;

    public TypingKeyboard(string text, int intervalBetweenKeys, blah blah blah){}

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        foo = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("keysoundthinggy");
    }
}
```

In order to hear sounds you need to load the sounds, and store them. This happens for every instance of the class I have.

So every time you make this class, you need to call `LoadContent` and it loads the `SoundEffect` to the RAM. This is not very efficient since I always use the same sounds.

[image: Illustration of the problem]

Is there a way that I can create a class that you need to make an instance of once and then can call the sounds from "anywhere" I want?

Like this:

```
// I need to play the sound!
TypingKeyboardData.Foo.Play();
```

Comment: I would create a sound class and pass by reference that class to all the other classes

Comment: Better yet make the sound class static. Then call a static method from that class to play the sound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [lazy singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) pattern:

```
public class TypingKeyboardData
{
    private static readonly Lazy<TypingKeyboardData> _instance
        = new Lazy<TypingKeyboardData>(() => new TypingKeyboardData());
    // private to prevent direct instantiation.
    private TypingKeyboardData()
    {
    }
    // accessor for instance
    public static TypingKeyboardData Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    // Add all required instance methods below
}
```

More [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx).